# Why so many thermal insulation tiles on Starship are marked broken?

Tags: spacex-starship

From the photos it seems that about 40% of the tiles were marked with orange strips at some moment, while another 30% with green strips as misaligned. Why the percentage is so high? Why they could not attach the most of them correctly from the first attempt?

Did they break after being attached? Can they similarly break down any moment? Are they so brittle and weak?

Comment: General SpaceX philosophy is to try something and if it doesn't work, try something else, rather than worrying about getting it right the first time.  See, for example, [how not to land a rocket](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bvim4rsNHkQ), or the five tries it took to get the Starship flip maneuver and landing right.